# Kiwi TCMS V12.2 does not send email when test plan or test cases change

Tags: kiwi-tcms

Kiwi TCMS V12.2 does not send email when test plan or test cases change.

I followed instructions in the documentation to configure SMTP for sending e-mails. Here is the `local-settings.py` file:

```
SERVER_EMAIL = DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'kiwitcms@example.com'
# additional Kiwi TCMS setting
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = '[Kiwi-TCMS] '

# AWS SES HOST
EMAIL_HOST = '<removed>'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '<removed>'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '<removed>'

# Enable TLS
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Here is the relevant part of `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
    web:
        container_name: kiwi_web
        depends_on:
            - db
        restart: always
        image: kiwitcms/kiwi:v12.2
#        image: kiwitcms/kiwi:latest
        ports:
            - 80:8080
            - 443:8443
        volumes:
            - uploads:/Kiwi/uploads:Z
            - ./local_settings.py:/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/tcms/settings/local_settings.py
```

The test e-mail and e-mail for changing password both work OK. I receive the e-mails and I can actually follow the link and change the password.

However, when I change the test plan or a test case, making sure the e-mail notifications are turned on appropriately in both cases, I do not get any e-mails. I checked the SMTP server and there were no rejected nor bounced messages. There was also no received messages for that particular time. So, I suspect that simply messages are not sent for some reason.

Is there anything else I need to configure so that the messages would also be sent when test plan or test cases change?

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be a mismatch in user expectations which will be made more clear in the UI. More context at:
https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/issues/3212#issuecomment-1563483154

Comment: Not really. It was more about a lack of proper documentation regarding how to configure SMTP to work. For example, the instructions for making AWS SES serve as a backend were incomplete without any hint as to the type of access key that needs to be created on the AWS side, etc. There were several problems within Kiwi TCMS that were making the debugging of this problem very hard and time consuming. Calling it "mismatch of user expectations" IMHO is a misrepresentation. Proper solution may be found here: https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/issues/3212#issuecomment-1563675699